# Keeping all the observations from a subset

Tags: r

I'm trying to create two different subsets from a big data frame. Here's the code :

```
amelioration <- subset(resilience, 
         (subset(resilience, resilience$YEAR==2010)$SCORE>
         subset(resilience, resilience$YEAR==2009)$SCORE))
```

The purpose is to select the observations which have a better score in 2010 than in 2009. 
The problem is that in the new table (amelioration), **the lines for 2009 and 2010 are missing** but i want to keep them.

It should look like this :

```
ID  |  YEAR  | SCORE
--------------------
177 | 2008   | 14
--------------------
177 | 2009   | 11
--------------------
177 | 2010   | 17
--------------------
177 | 2011   | 16
```

But it looks like this instead :

```
ID  |  YEAR  | SCORE
--------------------
177 | 2008   | 14
--------------------
177 | 2011   | 16
```

I tried with the  *which* command but it doesn't work either. What should I do ?

Comment: Could you show a small reproducible example input example instead of the intermediate output

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table you can recast your year variable over score, and filter directly on years.

```
ambivalence = data.table(ambivalence)
castedDF = dcast(ambivalence, id ~ year, fun.aggregate = sum)
targetRows = castedDF[`2010` > `2009`]
```